# IPC: WM_COPYDATA + serialization/deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, wm-copydata

I am currently working on 2 .NET apps which must communicate with each other. Simple Windows Messaging was chosen and this works nicely at the moment.
The data that is sent in the messages is a simple string, but now I have created a message class which contains a command (enum) and a data (string) member, and later possible other members.

When I send an instance of such an message class, it is serialized to bytes and then converted to a base64 string. This is then sent out using Windows' SendMessage().
On the other side I do the opposite. Eventually, the original object is restored and available in the other app.

While this mechanism seems to work, I was wondering if this is safe to do.
Indeed, there is some overhead, base64 string is much longer than the original string solution (but I would have to parse this tring manually to get command and data part)
Is there a maximum size for messages that can be sent with SendMessage ?

Also I'd rather stay away from .NET remoting for this project and stay with the SendMessage solution.

Any idea's ? Maybe use JSON instead to limit the overhead ?

Thanks.

Pika

Comment: This is so "old school" it brought a tear to my eye...

Comment: It brought a tear to my eye too, but not the "oh man, I miss those days" kind of tear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use XDMessaging (http://xdmessaging.codeplex.com/) which supports WM_COPYDATA, Named pipes and IOStream messaging- providing a highly flexible, robust and tested solution, instead of rolling something yourself.

How about using Binary Serialization on your class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4abbf6k0(v=VS.71).aspx) with XDMessaging? It would be quite compact and very easy to implement.

Comment: Under the hood I'm already using XDMessaging. It works quite well indeed, but you can only send strings with it. Using [Serializable] and BinaryFormatter gives me a byte array that is longer than the method I was using, but they both work.

Comment: As it seems, the aproach I was using resulted in objects that did not correctly deserialize. I then used the method you described and this works correctly. Thanks!

Comment: The library now supports sending of serializable objects

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to send messages look at a message bus architecture like [Rhino Service Bus](http://ayende.com/Blog/category/554.aspx) or [NServiceBus](http://nservicebus.com/).  They will provide a relatively simple and much more robust messaging implementation.

Comment: Interesting, but for now I only need IPC on the same machine.

Comment: A message bus system will work between two processes on the same machine also.  And if you need to work between two machines later the change is a "no brainer".

Answer (score 0):

I'd really recommend using a more modern, scalable approach.  For example, you could easily use [named pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.namedpipeserverstream.aspx) to communicate, and just use standard stream functionality instead of trying to send messages that need to be encoded.

(Personally, I'd probably use [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx), as that has so many benefits, including allowing this to work across different machines for free...)

Comment: True, the problem is I have to stick with the .NET 2.0 Framework. I may look into named pipes in the future however.

Comment: @pika81: It sounds like you've found a solution, but if not, you can consider just using something that provides named pipe support for .net 2, like: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/interprocess-communication-using-named-pipes-in-csharp

Comment: Thx, I also found this very usefull post: http://blog.benday.com/archive/2008/06/22/23182.aspx